# Setting env variable for buildpack on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm trying to use a specific version of pdftotext (version 3.03) on Heroku. I'm using https://github.com/carwow/heroku-buildpack-pdftotext buildpack which by default uses version 0.57 (from what I'm seeing it's including Poppler version 0.57, but pdftotext version is 0.57 as well). I'm assuming, from looking at https://github.com/carwow/heroku-buildpack-pdftotext/blob/master/scripts/build_pdftotext, that this buildpack allows to use specific version of Poppler by providing either `POPPLER_VERSION` or `POPPLER_TARBALL_URL` variables. The question is - how can I pass these variables to the build step?

What I've tried so far:

- setting `POPPLER_VERSION` and `POPPLER_TARBALL_URL` in `Config Vars`, deploying
- per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api, (I assume) creating `env` folder within my application, setting `ENV_DIR` to `env`, creating `POPPLER_VERSION` and `POPPLER_TARBALL_URL` files containing appropriate values within `env` folder, deploying

In either case, when running `/app/bin/pdftotext` version 0.57 is still being reported

Comment: Have you looked at https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/loadsmart/env-buildpack to make specific config/env vars available at build time?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've looked at it, but haven't tried it given that the repository has been archived; it seems that it's doing the same thing as the Buildpack API, so I'd like to use official way, if it's possible

Comment: The buildpack API is what you'd implement if you were *writing a buildpack*, like the env buildpack.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh, I clearly misunderstood the purpose of this API then. It seems weird to me though that I need to install a buildpack to set environment variable in another buildpack. Would expect that there's a Heroku mandated way of doing that

Comment: I think config vars *should* be available to all of the buildpacks, although I have noticed (see https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/issues/1) that it seems to depend on how they're set - if I do it immediately after creating the app via the CLI it's available, but if I set it from the `app.json` for the Deploy to Heroku button it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that anybody runs into this question - the answer is that I'm dumb and I expected Heroku to build binary using provided Makefile. But why should Heroku build it?

As such, I've forked the https://github.com/carwow/heroku-buildpack-pdftotext to https://github.com/eithed/heroku-buildpack-pdftotext, updated the script to use cmake, built it, switched Heroku to use my buildpack - version 20.10.0 is correctly installed.